# Rails Carrierwave stor_dir location not valid (Model.#{association} returns nil)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, upload, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave to upload images to my webapp.

It has become necessary to upload them to the location of the parent model.

Ie.

The parent is house which has many images.

So I want to store the images in

```
public/uploads/houses/images/[:house_id]/
```

This is my current setup.

```
..uploaders/image_uploader.rb

  def store_dir
    puts "uploads/house/#{model.house_id}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    "uploads/house/#{model.house_id}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

The puts statement prints out the correct path that I would like but the path saved does not match.
It appears that the model.house_id is returning nil

House Model

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :description, :title, :price, :image, :image_id, :images, :image_cache
  has_many :images
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Image Model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :house_id, :image
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :house
end
```

How do I get the correct path/ What am I doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
def cache_dir
"#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/houses/images"
end
def store_dir
  "#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```